# Dynamic reference within Excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, reference, excel-indirect

How can I use the content in a cell in a separate formula?

I have in cell A1 the following content: `$BA$10:$BA$150`
This content will change on a regular basis. So next time it could be: `$BZ$10:$BZ$150`.

In a different cell, same sheet, I need to use a SUMIFS function:

```
=SUMIFS(Sheet1!$BA$10:$BA$150,Sheet1!$N$10:$N$150,'Summary '!X$13)
```

I would like in this formula instead of writing $BA$10:$BA$150 I want to use the content in cell A1. I tried to use the indirect function but it didn't work:

```
=SUMIFS(Sheet1!&INDIRECT(A1),Sheet1!$N$10:$N$150,'Summary '!X$13))
```

Any ideas please?

Comment: How did you implement the indirect() function?

Comment: =SUMIFS(Sheet1!&INDIRECT(A1),Sheet1!$N$10:$N$150,'Summary '!X$13))

Comment: Add this pertinent information to your original question, leaving it in a comment is not good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try applying:

```
 INDIRECT("Sheet1!"&A1)
```

(The trailing space in the sheet name `Summary` seems just a nuisance.)

I would agree the official documentation could be clearer in this respect.
(...but there are many examples on SO!)

(Good example why *show what you've tried* is useful.)